# Puppet Class: define a variable which list all files in a directory

Tags: class, module, puppet

I'm defining my own Puppet class, and I was wondering if it is possible to have an array variable which contains a list of all files in a specific directory. I was wondering to have a similar syntax like below, but didn't found a way to make it work.

```
$dirs = Dir.entries('C:\\Program Files\\Java\\')
```

Does anyone how to do it in a Puppet file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to have an array variable which contains a list of all files in a specific directory.

Information about the current state of the machine to be configured is conveyed to the catalog compiler via *facts*.  These are available to your classes as top-scope variables, and Puppet (or Facter, actually) provides [ways to define your own custom facts](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/fact_overview.html).  That's a link into the Facter 3 manual, but similar applies to earlier versions.  Do not overlook the rest of the Facter documentation, which has more relevant information on this topic.

On the other hand, information about the machine providing catalog-building services -- the master in a master / agent setup -- can be obtained by writing and calling a [custom function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/functions_basics.html).  This is rarely what you actually want, but it's worth mentioning because you might one day want a custom function for some other purpose.